# calculating weekday from date

Tags: java, date

Why is any day in Jan Month giving me wrong DAY in my code?(happening only for the year 1994)

```
public class Ques1
{
public static void main(String args[])
    {
```

//Assuming we know the day on 6th June 2007 was Wednesday, assigning 0,1,2,3...6 to Mon,Tue,Wed...Sun

```
    int my_birth_year = 1996;
    int my_birth_month = 1;
    int my_birth_date = 2;
    int j = 2;
    for(int i = 2006;i>=(my_birth_year);i--)
    {
        if((i+1)%4==0 || (i+1)%400==0)
        {j = ((j-2)+7)%7;if(j<0) j = j*-1;}
        else if(i%100==0)
        {j = ((j-1)+7)%7;if(j<0) j = j*-1;}
        else
        {j = ((j-1)+7)%7;if(j<0) j = j*-1;}
    }
    System.out.println(j);//day on 6th June my_birth_YEAR
    int june = 6;
    int days_june = 30;
    if( june< my_birth_month)
    {
        int d,s;
        int h = my_birth_month - june;
        switch(h)
        {
        case 1 : d = 24 + my_birth_date;
                     j = (j+(d%7))%7; break;
        case 2 : d = 24 + 31 + my_birth_date;
                     j = (j+(d%7))%7; break;
        case 3 : d = 24 + 31+ 31+my_birth_date;
                 j = (j+(d%7))%7; break;
        case 4 : d = 24 + 31 +31+30+ my_birth_date;
                 j = (j+(d%7))%7; break;
        case 5 : d = 24 + 31+31+30+30+my_birth_date;
                 j = (j+(d%7))%7; break;
        case 6 : d = 24 + 31 +31+30+31+30+ my_birth_date;
                 j = (j+(d%7))%7; break;
        default : break;
        }
    }
    else if(june > my_birth_month)
    {
    int d;
    int h = june - my_birth_month;
        switch(h)
        {
        case 1 : d = 6+(31-my_birth_date);
             j = (-j+(d%7))%7; break;
        case 2 : d = 6 + 31 +30 - my_birth_date;
             j = (-j+(d%7))%7; break;

        case 3 : d = 6 + 31+ 30+31-my_birth_date;
             j = (-j+(d%7))%7; break;

        case 4 :if(my_birth_year %4 == 0 || my_birth_year%400 == 0)
                d = 6 + 31 +30+31+ 29 - my_birth_date;
            else
                d = 6 + 31 +30+31+ 28 - my_birth_date;
            j = (-j+(d%7))%7; break;
```

This is the case for January :

```
        case 5 :if(my_birth_year %4 == 0 || my_birth_year%400 == 0)
                d = 6 + 31 +30+31+ 29 +31 - my_birth_date;
            else
                d = 6 + 31 +30+31+ 28 + 31 - my_birth_date; 
            j = (-j+(d%7))%7; break;
        default : break;
        }
    }
    if(j<0) j = j*-1;
    switch (j)
    {
        case 0 : System.out.println("Monday");
             break;

        case 1 : System.out.println("Tuesday");
             break;

        case 2 : System.out.println("Wednesday");
             break;

        case 3 : System.out.println("Thursday");
             break;

        case 4 : System.out.println("Friday");
             break;

        case 5 : System.out.println("Saturday");
             break;

        case 6 : System.out.println("Sunday");
             break;

        default : System.out.println("Error");
             break;
    }
}
```

}

P.S. : I am writing the code without using APIs

Comment: Have you considered using `java.util.Calendar` for that?

Comment: What's that? Assembly language?

Comment: @Aleksandr M : I want to do it without importing any packages

Answer (score 1):

Your code is heinous in every way.  I'll guess that you don't realize that [months are zero-based](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) in the Date and Calendar classes, so January = 0, December = 11.

Comment: January = 0, not January = 1

Comment: I haven't used any APIs...I wish to make my own code for calculation.

Comment: irrelevant.  January is still zero.  Write your own code if you must, but you need to do a better job than this.  It's ugly, unreadable, and wrong in every way.

Comment: thank you for the correction.  coffee hasn't kicked in yet.  numbers don't match verbiage.

Comment: I do not see how the legacy classes `Date` and `Calendar` apply here. They are not used in the Question’s code. The point of the Question is to make an exercise of *not* using such classes.